# Can MVC Areas be a subfolder (i.e. xyz/Areas)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Just to clarify, suppose there are 2 areas, ContactManager and BugTracker. Below is how I am trying to structure the folders:

Root
   xyz/Areas/ContactManager
   xyz/Areas/BugTracker

I am new to MVC. I was going to look into the use of ViewLocationFormats.

Comment: Yes, there isn't problem. Why not try it?